# autotools not removing certain folders and files

Tags: linux, makefile, autotools

I'm using autotools to package my software and compile. The problem I'm having is that during the installation process, I'm creating a folder in /etc/myapp and in that folder I'm placing several files that I need. In addition, when my software is running, I'm generating files and storing them in that same location (/etc/myapp). When I execute "sudo make uninstall", all of the files that were initially installed by using "sudo make install" are removed from /etc/myapp. However, the files that are generated by the software and store in that same spot are not removed and now I have left over files.

Where in the Makefile.am files would I specify to remove the entire /etc/myapp folder during the uninstall process?

FYI, I'm using Ubuntu 12.

Thank you
D

Comment: When you say /etc/myapp, you really mean `$(datadir)/myapp` or `$(pkgdatadir)` or something similar, right? You cannot specify hard coded paths, since the user must be allowed to specify them at configure and/or make time, or your package is horribly broken. This is much easier to get right when you project is young than it is to fix it later, so it would be wise to get it right before you go too much further.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Makefile.am`, you can create a target named [`uninstall-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#index-uninstall_002dhook) which will delete your generated files:

```
uninstall-hook:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/my_generated_file $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)/my_other_generated_file
```

Or even:

```
uninstall-hook:
    rm -rf $(DESTDIR)$(datadir)
```

Comment: Hey jml, thanks for the reponse. I will go ahead and try it out!

Comment: @DavidNA You can add it anywhere you want. But for more readability, I think this is better to add it near to the place you define the `install` targets. So, for most automake packages, in `src/Makefile.am`.

Comment: Ackk, no!!!  What will happen if the user installs with prefix set somewhere else or with `make DESTDIR=/some/other/path install`?  One of the major features of automake is that the user gets to specify the destination and the files may not end up in /etc.  If the pacakge does not allow that then it is broken.

Comment: Or even worse, what if the user has installed some other application in `/etc/myapp` and you just blew their stuff away?  That user will be very upset (and rightly so) with the maintainer of this package.

Answer (score 0):

Your question involves more than just tooling; it involves policy.  What type of files are you creating?  If they can be lost over a reboot, they (probably) belong under /var/run/myapp.  If they are data files, they probably belong in $(prefix)/share/myapp.  I say "probably" because it depends on the platform, and the user.  Most debian users will want such files in the locations I mention above, but they may have reasons for putting them elsewhere. The important point is that it is the user's choice, not yours.  As the package maintainer, you don't get to choose /etc/myapp.  You need to configure your package to make those choices available to the user.  The typical way to do that is to use automake's _DATA primaries and the 'sysconfdir', 'sharedstatedir', 'localstatedir', and 'pkgdatadir' family of variables.